# PHP JSON Post string from Textbox (Searchbox) and return result in textbox as string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am trying to create a simple webpage like goggle, where user type there search for e.g  "What is England?"   and Json post the string from searchbox to specified URL (for e.g. Like Goggle search API) with username and password authentication and return the result from given url back to the webpage as answer.

I really need a simple idea of sample code. As i am very new in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using AJAX, you can do this in jquery its really easy just search jquery docs, you can also do this in many other ways like pure js...

**EDIT:**

here is a simple example ,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search example</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./content.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="searchInput" />

<input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" value="Click to search" />


</body>


</html>
```

and this is jquery code (content.js):

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#searchSubmit').on('click', function(){
        var text_to_search = $('#searchInput').val(); //get searchbox text to send using ajax
        $.ajax ({
            data: ({ text: text_to_search }), //these are the GET, POST variables that you want to send to backend 
            //(in this case we are sending text as post variable)
            method: "POST",
            url: "./backend.json", //the url you want to send the request to..
            success: function(result) { // (result) variable is the data you the backend sent back
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function() {
                //failed to 
                alert("couldnt contact backend..");
            }
        });

    }); 
})
```

in the example above on ajax succes jquery will alert any text that the backend gave back...

Comment: do you know any code example?

Comment: ok wait a minute i will write a simple ajax using jquery

Comment: Thank you very much @Diyar Baban. But The url i wanna direct it to require username and password. How do i code that? and also when i query the string from url it will give the string result. Like asking a question from the goggle and getting one answer back

Comment: you're welcome, no you cant do that ! you only can pass the request and get back the result..

Comment: well.. thats what i created as an example

Comment: but unfortunately, the webservice (url) i want to pass my Question string requires a login before entering the Webservice API....

Comment: you can generate a token id and pass it to the backend instead of login in or you can also login by passing username/password sessions/variables to the backend i just answered your question i don't write code

Comment: Great... thank you....thank you for your help

Comment: you're welcome if your problem is solved you ca mark the answer as solved @Lucky

Comment: i have input the URL but it doesnt find it Webservice........................................

url: "https://test.ihost.com/", //the url you want to send the request to..
   request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:Password"));

Comment: can you show me your code ?